# Moments of inertia

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

I know the concept of moment of inertia from $L=I \omega$, $\tau =I \alpha$, $I=mr^2$, and so on.

I also know the that, in general, $I=\int r^2dm$

I would like to know how we derived the moments of inertia of some regular shaped bodies like rings, discs, spheres (hollow, solid), cone (hollow, solid), thin rod, and so on.

[image]

The image is from my textbook. But my textbook doesn't provide the derivations.

I also referred to [List of moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia) of inertia on Wikipedia but it also doesn't provide the derivations.

Comment: You will get numerous videos regarding the derivations on YouTube. 
Also check this out : https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Book%3A_University_Physics_I_-_Mechanics_Sound_Oscillations_and_Waves_(OpenStax)/10%3A_Fixed-Axis_Rotation__Introduction/10.06%3A_Calculating_Moments_of_Inertia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the definition of mass density, $\text dm=\rho\,\text dV$, where $\rho$ is the density of the object. Furthermore, these tables assume a constant density for objects of total mass $M$ and volume $V$, so $\rho=M/V$ across the entire integration.

Therefore, the integral becomes

$$I=\int r^2\,\text dm=\iiint r^2\rho\,\text dV=\frac MV\iiint r^2\,\text dV$$

From here, you just perform the integral over the space of the object, and you have the moment of inertia.

For example, consider a cylinder of mass $M$, radius $R$, and height $h$ about its center axis (item 7 on your table). The volume is $V=\pi R^2h$, and the integral (easily done in cylindrical coordinates) is

$$
I=\frac{M}{\pi R^2h} \int_0^h\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^Rr^2\cdot(r\,\text dr\,\text d\theta\,\text dz)
$$

The integrals in $z$ and $\theta$ are trivial due to lack of $z$ and $\theta$ dependence in the integrand, and the $r$ integral is just integration of a polynomial

$$
I=\frac{M}{\pi R^2h}\cdot\left(2\pi\cdot h\cdot\frac14R^4\right)=\frac12MR^2
$$

In general each integral will be different, and how to best approach them well depend on the geometry, but the procedure is always the same.